# Bad performance image segmentation on new data

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, classification, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am making image segmentation with U-net architecture. My task is to do segmentation to cars. I am using Carvana Image Dataset provided by Kaggle. In both train and test, I have great accuracy. I made data augmentation(zoom, rotate) but still when i enter data like this:
[image: this]
or this:
[image: this]
I am getting terrible output, e.g.:
[image: Output for second image]
Both images are 224x224 as train and test sets. And here is my train-test inputs:
[image: train]
[image: test]
What might be the problem?

Comment: not enough training data. a single picture? really? I know U-net is supposed to be good but some things are just beyond possible.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz no no, it's just an example picture of my training dataset.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz my training-testing dataset is here https://www.kaggle.com/c/carvana-image-masking-challenge